# Get Names from string values

Tags: c#, regex

I have a `string` as shown below.

How do i extract the name from both such that for the example below the result would be:

**Input String:**

> \\DF3\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="DF3",Name="Administrators"

**Output:**

> Administrators

Comment: split the string by `Name=`

Comment: @Rahul that will return "Administrators" will it not rather than Administrators

Comment: Yes, replace quotes `"` after that.

Comment: agreed but a one liner is better

Comment: @user1438082 you can also try regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var input = "\\DF3\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain=\"DF3\",Name=\"Administrators\"";

var name = input.Split(new[] { "Name=" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Last().Trim('"');
```

First `Split` your string by `Name=`, get the last part then use `Trim` and remove the double-quotes.

Comment: I would use verbatim `@`; no need of escaping.

Comment: @Rahul still you need to escape double-quotes (using twice) :) that looks worse I think :)

Comment: I believe it's not the most optimal solution, because it grabs and the rest of the string too. If we rely on this format of a string, then we can simply cut off the last char and find `LastIndexOf('"')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `regex` to match what you want.. in case you dont want to use `split`

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = "\\DF3\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain=\"DF3\",Name=\"Administrators\"";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, "Name=\\\"(.*?)\\\"").Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```